# what does it mean if the discriminator of a GAN always returns the same value?

Tags: overfitting, gan

I have a trained Generative Adversarial Networks [GAN](http://blog.aylien.com/introduction-generative-adversarial-networks-code-tensorflow/). When I input real and fake images to the discriminator, the returned value is always the same?
Is this a sort of overfitting of the discriminator?
What else can be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unfortunately one of the issues when training GANs. Intuitively, there's nothing wrong: the point of $G$(Generator) is to produce examples that $D$(Discriminator) thinks are real and not fake. So an obvious solution is for $G$ to explicitly copy a few training images, or just settle on few examples that it found which work well. In other words, there's nothing encouraging *diversity* in G's predictions.

The GAN minimization is theoretically done simultaneously between the generator $G$ and the discriminator $D$, but in practice must alternate between gradient descent on $G$ and $D$. The trick is to balance the alternation. If you spend too much time on minimizing $G$, then $D$ will most likely collapse to a few states.

In your link, refer to the section on "Improving sample diversity" where they discuss recent results on using minibatches to avoid collapse. In particular, see section 2 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03498.pdf

Comment: You have completely messed up the notations. I guess It's the generator that copies while you mention it as D.

Comment: Have made edits

Comment: And it doesn't answer the question either